# Predicting average duration till success for rolls at fixed intervals with increasing chances.

Tags: probability

This is for a game, where a research project has an increasing probability of finishing, which is challenged at regular intervals.

A project has a maximum duration. Every 12 minutes we roll a number between zero and the remaining duration. If that number is smaller than a specific static value, the project finishes.

I'd like to inform the player of the expected average duration, but I have no idea where to start and failed to find similar examples. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Work recursively:  if $E_M$ is the expected duration (with $M$ the initial max), then the project ends immediately with probability $\frac sM$, where $s$ is the fixed number.  Otherwise it continues, only with shorter max.  Thus $E_M=\frac sM\times 0 +\frac {M-s}M\times (E_{M-12}+12)$.  Adjust this if I guessed wrong about how the game starts (my rules allow the game to take no time at all, if the initial roll is small.  Not sure if that's what you intended.).

Comment: That works. Thanks!